# parallelizing NetworkX's isChordal Function with Multiprocessing/multithreading

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, networkx, python-multiprocessing

Is it possible to utilize multiprocessing to execute NetworkX's isChordal function in parallel? I've experimented with the concurrent.futures module in Python, but it appears that the computational runtime is worse than using a simple for loop. I'm curious if there is an alternative approach to parallelize the isChordal function  Or if parallelizing the isChordal function in Python is not a feasible option?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
def checkChordal(Adj_matrix):
    # function determines whether a chain component is chordal or not
    # input:  undirected adjacency matrix ( in pandas dataFrame)) of an undirected graph 
    # outputs: true (yes) or false(no)

    # convert dataframe to np.array and extract all the nonzero elements.
    x, y = np.nonzero(np.array(Adj_matrix))
    # make a list of tuples of the non zero indices in the dataframe
    indexNonzero = list(zip(x, y))
    if indexNonzero == []:  # if graph is empty
        return True  # empty graph is still chordal
    G1 = nx.Graph(indexNonzero)
    try:
        return nx.is_chordal(G1)
    except nx.NetworkXError as e:
        if str(e) == "Input graph is not chordal.":
            return False


def process_isChordal_in_parallel(L):
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            # ProcessPoolExecutor()  assigns the task to one of the worker processing
            results = []
            final_result = []
            for i in range(len(L)):
                result = executor.submit(checkChordal, L[i])
                results.append(result)
            for result in results:
                final_result.append(result.result())  # result.result() blocks and waits until workers process completes the computation
        return final_result
```